# How to use the js library bowser?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, npm

I want to use the js library bowser in an asp.net project which uses TypeScript and the bundling/minification features that exists in the namespace System.Web.Optimization.

The library bowser can be found here: https://github.com/lancedikson/bowser

I have tried to read the documentation for the project but I cant find out how I should add the library to my solution. Does not it exists a minified version of the library that I just can add to my project? It seems like I should add the library with npm when I am reading the documentation.

Unfortunately I am a rookie when it comes to npm. If I add a dependency in my package.json with the following  row '"bowser": "2.4.0"', and then restores all packages I get bowser in my node_modules folder. So far so good...

Now I create a ts-file (bowsertest.ts):

```
import * as Bowser from "bowser";

class BowserTest {
    constructor() {
        const browser = Bowser.getParser(window.navigator.userAgent);
        console.log(`The current browser name is "${browser.getBrowserName()}"`);
    }
}
```

I reference the js file that is compiled for the ts-file above and reference it from a page:

```
<script src="bowsertest.js"></script>
```

But of course this will not work, since I have not loaded any js-files for bowser. How should I load the js files? Make a bundle with all js files in node_modules\bowser\src and reference it before my bowsertest.js is read?

I am lost. :)